# Deployment on IIS of Nestjs application

Tags: node.js, deployment, nestjs

I have tried to deploy my Nestjs deploying on IIS server. I have configured **iisnode** on **IIS** that works **fine** for **express application** but I am getting errors for **missing modules** for nestjs.  I have tried following commands for building production package

> npm run start:prod

and

> npm run webpack

but failed to deploy on IIS. How can I build a deployment package?? so I can deploy. I am new with nodejs and Nestjs.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the project's package.json.  You'll see that start:prod is a script that runs node on the compiled output of the project. You get the compiled output by running:

```
npm run prestart:prod
```

that will re-build your app into the dist folder.

So you can

1. Zip up the dist folder
2. deploy to the target host
3. Unzip it
4. Try running iisnode on it

let me know how that works