# Is it possible to run an Nest.js application on windows iis?

Tags: windows, iis, nestjs, iisnode

i have an Nest.js application that i want to run on windows IIS Server. 
I installed allready the iisnode module github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode
and created a new website and application on IIS

I am Able to call my Api endpoints but getting following Message:

Warning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

The Problem is that i dont use Buffer() im my code its only used in some Node-Modules used within my project.

Before i spent more time on solving the deprecated warning i just wanted to be sure, wheter runnig nest.js applications on IIS with iisnode is possible in general?

Thanks a lot for your help

This is my web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <!-- indicates that the hello.js file is a node.js application 
    to be handled by the iisnode module -->

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="sendToNode">
          <match url="/*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  ...

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
'''
```

Comment: IISNode was developed to serve Node.js web apps on Azure App Service when there was only Windows OS there. However, Azure App Service now supports Linux/Docker fully, so such projects (Node.js/Python on IIS) are out-of-maintenance (https://github.com/Azure/iisnode has been idle for two years). Effectively that's a hint you shouldn't attempt to run Node.js on IIS. Can you switch to Linux?

Comment: Hi Lex Li , thanks for your quick answer. No, unfortunatly not :-(

Comment: your error is not related to iis. based on warning new Buffer() should be replaced with one of:Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe() or Buffer.from(). [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165333/deprecationwarning-buffer-is-deprecated-due-to-security-and-usability-issues) ,[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53046414/deployment-on-iis-of-nestjs-application)

Answer (score 1):

**Start From zero**

[Install urlrewrite fist if not](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Here We are going a crerate *hello world* project and *host in iis* server

So Install nest globaly your preference i am using this approach

```
npm install -g @nestjs/cli
```

So Create new nest project

```
nest new myhost
```

[image]

Then Move to that folder  by this=>

```
cd myhost
npm run start
```

[image]

Here i change *3000* port to *4444* you can change as your wish

[image]

Just build your Project and now *dist* folder created

```
 npm run build
```

[image]

Now install pm2 node package this package as background service [pm2link](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

[image]
Now you Can check the link http://localhost:4444/

[image]

Now Open iis (internet information service)

```
==> Add Website
        ==>Add site name
        ==>Add Physical path as you build folder 
        ==> Add Port not 4444 because our node project running on that port so use different port
```

[image]

Now Click on url rewrite for redirect port 4445 (iis hosted port) to 4444(project running port)

[image]

Select Reverse proxy

[image]

Add reverse proxy rule

[image]

Now check your browser work on both port

[image]
web.config may like this above config enough

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:4444/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still in search of an answer on how to host NestJs application on IIS, you have to make use of `URLRewrite` and PM2 (IISNode is not required):

Install `URLRewrite` module in your IIS.

Install [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

**The idea is to run your NestJs application via PM2 and then setup a reverse proxy in IIS that redirects all inbound requests to the running NestJS application.**

First make sure your application is running via PM2. Navigate to the folder where your `main.js` file is, and run `pm2 start main.js`

Then, configure NestJS application to run on a port of your choice in IIS.

Then, setup a reverse proxy setting in `web.config` that redirects to the actual port that your NestJs application is running on. My `web.config` looks like this, where I'm redirecting the inbound request to `localhost:3333`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3333/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And that's it. Your NestJs application will now successfully run on IIS.

Refer this wonderful [link](https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

1. **In order to remedy the warning**: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

Under "C:\Program Files\iisnode" modify the "interceptor.js" file at line 169. Replace `return new Buffer(data, typeof encoding === 'string' ? encoding: 'utf8');` by `return Buffer.from(data, typeof encoding === 'string'? encoding: 'utf8');`

That will solved this problem caused by iisnode itself.

2. **In order to launch a Nestjs application via iisnode only** (i.e. without resorting to the reverse proxy).

First, be sure "URLRewrite" is installed and your "web.config" file is as follows :

```xml
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="iisnode" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
    
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="HTTP to Prod HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <!-- Don't interfere with requests for logs -->
            <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.js\.logs\/\d+\.txt$" />
            </rule>
            <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
            <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^main.js\/debug[\/]?" />
            </rule>
            <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the public folder -->
            <rule name="StaticContent">
              <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
            </rule>
            <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js application entry point -->
            <rule name="DynamicContent">
              <conditions>
                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Then, modify your "main.ts" file as follows :

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as process from 'process';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const normalizePort = (val) => {
  const port = parseInt(val, 10);
  if (isNaN(port)) {
    return val;
  }
  if (port >= 0) {
    return port;
  }
  return false;
};

dotenv.config();

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || process.env.APP_PORT);

  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();
```

Note the use of process.env.PORT delivered by IIS site binding and process.env.APP_PORT from .env file as follows :

```
# SERVER
APP_PORT=3000
```